# Offline installation of a package (PyPlot) in JULIA

Tags: julia, julia-plots

In Julia, A package can be installed through `using Pkg`; `Pkg.add("PyPlot")` directly.

But how can the same package be installed offline?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It is difficult to answer this question, but if I have right understanding than you are using Laptop. Sometimes, when you just close Laptop while installing or upgrading application it continue the update in order to avoid unwanted error